# AllowsInlineMedia Playback Broken in iOS 13.4

Tags: cordova, wkwebview

Any device I have with 13.4 now ignores "AllowsInlineMediaPlayback" set to true and webkit-playsinline and playsinline set on the video source in WKWebView.

Help! How do we fix this with Cordova?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, WKWebView is borked for iframe video-js embeds, like the Brightcove default embed my app was using - previous OS iterations all work fine and respect the playsinline declarations. I switched everything to loading dynamically (with playsinline) with a callback function and it works without opening the internal player like it's supposed to.

Not fun.